# How to let eclipse refresh the workspace

Tags: eclipse, svn

I write a *bat-script to update my workspace projects to HEAD revision.
The problem is that I stil have to need refresh the workspace in project explorer of eclipse manually.
(Otherwise, new files want shown)
Can I use "External Configuration" or something like that to run my bat and after finished that eclipse refreshes the workspace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use 'Run > External Tools > External Tools Configurations' to configure and run a Program.

This configuration has a 'Refresh' tab where you can configure the refresh action to take when the program finishes.